# How to run test methods in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, junit, buildpath

I want to run test methods of the test code files that are under /spring-boot/src/test/java/com/example/springboot/.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBL97.png)

I thought I need to use those files as source folder. However, when I build path /com/example/springboot, the import stuff can't be resolved.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krDqe.png)

So I want to know why the error happens, and how I can run the test methods, thank you.

Comment: In the first screenshot, the tests are not in a source folder, so they will not be compiled and therefore cannot be executed. In the second screenshot, the tests are in a regular instead of a test source folder, so test scope dependencies will not be resolved. Does right-click the project folder and _Maven > Update Project..._ fix your issue (I guess you edit the Java Build Path manually instead of doing this)? Otherwise, show your `pom.xml` (as text, not as screenshot).

Comment: @howler Problem solved thanks to your answer, thanks a lot!